How multi wallet transaction system can be implemented with some rules based on spending?
I'm working on a casino website and games are provided by an external provider.
Casino is only responsible with users and their wallets, and the provider communicates with our API to get user info, balance, etc.
When a user starts playing, providers send requests to indicate bets & wins. Accordingly, I add or subtract the amount from the user's wallet. No issues here. But there are a couple of crucial points;

Actions are not individual but in an array. For instance;

[
    {id:1, type:"bet", amount:100},
    {id:2, type:"win", amount:10},
    {id:3, type:"bet", amount:5}
    {id:4, type:"win", amount:50},
]


There is a possibility that the provider can send a "rollback" request. This means the same amount will be reverted to the account;

[
    {id:5, type:"rollback", ref_id:1, amount:100},
    {id:6, type:"rollback", ref_id:2, amount:10},
]


Rollbacks can be sent before the action request. (At this point I store it somewhere else, when the referenced action itself is received, I check if there is a rollback request for that action. If so, I add all requests at once.)

No issues up to this point.
The casino has a bonus feature. When a bonus is activated, there is a sub-wallet for the bonus. Users can use this wallet to play the game. When the total bet amount is reached to the goal, whatever is in the bonus wallet will be transferred to the main wallet.
I create transaction (chain) operations. Therefore if one record fails, it reverts all the operations. (Requirement)
Also sometimes actions can be sent twice, by the provider, this one is handles, as well (insert ignore)
My problems are;

If the user's spending goal is achieved by the (n)th action, after that point, the rest of the actions should be issued to the default wallet.
If a rollback is received, that might mean, the user did not reach the goal. Therefore, I might need to revert the transferred bonus amount back to the bonus wallet or something else.

This API runs on Google Cloud with Node.JS and Sequelize. I'm using PostgreSQL as a database.
I can't figure out how to handle these situations. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
I have these tables;
User, Wallets, Bonuses, Transactions, Pre_Rollbacks
Pre_Rollbacks
id, external_id, amount
Transaction table roughly goes as;
id, user_id, wallet_id, bonus_id, operationType, amount, ref_id, external_id
Wallets
id, user_id, balance isBonusWallet
Bonuses
id, user_id, goal, status
What kind of approach should I take to handle this situation or is there a design pattern that I can follow?
